# Syntax error, unrecognized expression jquery when using echo in php script after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got a script that gets the streetname and place automatically when typing the zip code and housenumber, this works perfectly but I want to show a message for when an address cannot be found.

So this is what I did:

```
if(!empty($data->_embedded->addresses)){
  // Loop het het aantal addresses objecten (1) en stop de data tussen de HTMl
  foreach($data->_embedded->addresses as $key => $resultset){
    $returndata = '
    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required" id="billing_address_1_field">
       <label for="billing_address_1" class="">Adres<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text readonlyinput" name="billing_address_1" id="billing_address" value="'.$resultset->street.'" readonly>
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required" id="billing_city_field" data-o_class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required">
       <label for="billing_city" class="">Plaats<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text readonlyinput" name="billing_city" id="billing_city" placeholder="" value="'.$resultset->city->label.'" readonly>
    </p>';
  }
}else{
  $returndata = 'Vul een geldig adres in.';
}
// Echo resultaat
echo $returndata;
```

But when I fill in a non existent address to make the message appear, I see nothing but this error message in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Vul een geldig adres in.
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.js:2)
    at n (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bestellen:944)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
```

Why is that? If I remove the echo there is no error. I've seen this issue before but never fixed it.

This is my jquery code:

```
// Haal de straatnaam en plaatsnaam op adhv huisnummer en postcode
tpj('#checkoutform').on('click', '.getaddressubtton', function(event) {
  // Stop de anchor tag van zijn normale gedrag
  event.preventDefault();
  // Haal de inhoud op van de spantags met class *cl
  var url = 'includes/getzip.php';
  var val1 = tpj('#billing_postcode').val();
  var val2 = tpj('#billing_housenumber').val();
  //Check of postcode en huisnummer beide zijn ingevuld
  if (val1 != '' && val2 != '') {
    //Post bovenstaande waardes naar url
    var posting = tpj.post( url, { postcode: val1, huisnummer: val2} );
    // Stop het resultaat in een div met de class .adresscript
    posting.done(function( data ) {
      var content = tpj( data );
      tpj( ".adresscript" ).empty().append( content );
    });
  } else {
    alert('Vul uw Postcode & Huisnummer in');
  }
});
```

Comment: @Stphane Only the comments and two texts are dutch, i can translate them if its a big deal.

Comment: return the else case text by wraping with a <p> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to create a jQuery element `tpj( data )` with a string `Vul een geldig adres in.` that is not HTML.

To fix that, you can append the string directly without creating a jQuery element.

```
// var content = tpj( data ); // NOT NEEDED
tpj( ".adresscript" ).empty().append( data );
```